# Rails4 - Testing - URLGenerationError: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, routes

I've read a lot of other questions here in SO but none could solve my issue (they all appeared to be parameters related). I hope someone can help me.

Executing my controller's test I get this message:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches 
    {:action=>"/login", :controller=>"sessions"}
test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in 
    <class:SessionsControllerTest>'
```

My `rake routes` looks like this:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern       Controller#Action
login  GET    /login(.:format)  sessions#new
       POST   /login(.:format)  sessions#create
logout DELETE /logout(.:format) sessions#destroy
```

My test itself is this one:

```
test "should get new" do
    puts 'debug: ' + login_path
    get login_path
    assert_response :success
end
```

The puts debug line prints: `debug: /login`

When I go to `localhost:3000/login` in my web browser it loads the page correctly and debug info sais that it used:

```
controller: sessions
action: new
```

Any idea why the test is not being correctly redirected to the `new` action and instead is looking for an inexistent action `/login`? Thanks!

EDIT: solution

Following answers below I found this link that explains the whole issue:

http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html

On Rails4 (which I'm using) the controllers test uses `ActionController::TestCase` where `get :new` must be used instead of `get login_url` (which is ok on integration tests).

Comment: Why are you using `get login_path` instead of just `get :new`?

Comment: Just following https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login Tried your code and worked. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder anyway whether it should work the tutorial style.

Comment: It should not. That book is getting outdated now; if you're using a version of Rails newer than the book did, there's no guarantee *anything* in it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test methods `get`, `post`, `delete`, etc., all assume that any parameter you pass them is the name of an *action* within the controller being tested. So, this call works:

```
get :new
```

because it generates `url_for(:controller => :sessions, :action => :new)`. This call doesn't:

```
get '/login'
```

because it generates `url_for(:controller => :sessions, :action => '/login')`.

Use the symbol form.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to test this using a url is to write `get login_url` instead of `get login_path`.

This is because the process of testing is not run inside a browser so the  `path` variable only consists `/login`, which is a **relative path**(which works when you see it through the browser since the path gets appended). On the other hand, the `url` variable is a Universal Resource Locator, hence it's an **absolute path** and it will work.

Comment: That way I get: `No route matches {:action=>"http://test.host/login", :controller=>"sessions"}`

Comment: @PacoAbato Erm, are you familiar with `test.host`?

Comment: I assume it's localhost. Anyway is a failed test: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"http://test.host/login", :controller=>"sessions"}`

Comment: @PacoAbato There is something wrong with your project if `test.host` is appearing. While you've already found a solution(which isn't the best IMO since the test is supposed to verify the route with the controller action), I'd advise you to fix this problem to avoid future errors which might be related.

Comment: @PacoAbato You can try printing out the value of `login_url` and see what it says.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal This is being done in the test environment, remember? `test.host` is fine. Also, my solution *does* verify the route -> controller action mapping, because it checks `url_for`.

Comment: `puts login_url` -> `http://test.host/login` It's possible that my project is not correctly configured. This is my first rails project.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I'm not saying that your solution is not fine. But the point of that test is to see if the absolute url opens the right controller. With your method, when the person runs the SessionsControllerTest file, it already is implying the controller is session and since you call :new directly, it becomes obvious.
PacoAbato I'm not sure about this, if ArtOfCode says its fine then it must be.

Comment: I'm trying an integration test and there `get login_path` is working ok. I guess it's there where the routing must be tested.

Comment: @PacoAbato Which rails version are you using?

Comment: rails --version -> Rails 4.2.5.1

Comment: @PacoAbato I'm on Rails 5.0.0.1 and the only tests that were generated for me were IntegrationTests. Since you're new to rails, why don't you use the latest version? It's updated for improvement. In models the tests are `ActiveSupport::TestCase`

Comment: Kind of forced to version 4. Thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: Rails 5, `_path` is working correctly in IntegrationTest by displaying only the relative path for me. You're welcome :)